# Use gulp-size to display total size of build

Tags: javascript, gulp

I'm trying to use `gulp-size` to display the total size of my final build directory.

Here is what I have:

```
gulp.task('build', ['copy:resources', 'copy:images', 'sass'], function() {
  return gulp.src(config.dist + '/**/*')
    .pipe(plugins.size({
      gzip: false,
      showFiles: true
    }));
});
```

When I run this multiple times, the displayed file list and total size keep changing.

Diffing the directory structure after the build is complete shows that the contents is exactly the same, which probably means the execution timing of the `gulp-size` task is not correct. I would expect it to run AFTER `'copy:resources', 'copy:images', 'sass'` are finished, but this doesn't seem to be the case.

Why isn't this running after all file copying is finished, or is there another way to show the final build size?

For reference, I am using gulp 3.9.0, and gulp-size 2.0.0.

Answer (score 2):

You can do simply:

```
gulp.task('size-dest', function() {
    console.log('Total file size in dist folder:');
  return gulp.src(config.dist + '/**/*')
    .pipe(size({showTotal: true, pretty: true}));
});
```

This task can be done after your build task in a sequence (see [gulp-sequence](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sequence)) as shown below:

```
gulp.task('build_size', function(cb) {
  return runSequence(
    'build',  /* your build task */
    'size-dest',
    cb);
});
```